# Liferay OpenCMIS integration with Alfresco

Tags: liferay, alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I want to integrate Alfresco repository to Liferay's document and media portlet and I've configured the same with CMIS Web-Services in control panel.

Custom properties (custom aspects created in Alfresco) are not visible in document details in Liferay while retrieving document details.

I found that to retrieve that information I need to integrate OpenCMIS in Liferay.
Do I need to do custom code implementation for the same? Do I need to write any hook/ext in Liferay to implement the same? Or I can do that with some configuration change in Liferay and Alfresco both.